# How to parse SOAP XML in Python properly using Etree?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, soap, elementtree

I'm trying to parse an xml response I get back as a string into something I can actually work with. So far I'm using xml.etree.ElementTree but it's not working properly.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_response = initialize_header(xml_param, 'AirService').text

#Take out SOAP envelope
xml_response=xml_response.split('<SOAP:Body>',1)[1].split('</SOAP:Body>',1)[0]

#Put into XML tree. Not perfect
root=ET.fromstring(xml_response)

#Basic info for first flight, dict
first_flight=root.find('{http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v29_0}AirPricingSolution').attrib

#root[5][2].attrib['TotalPrice']
return root, first_flight ,xml_response#, etree_to_dict(root)
```

When I access the children of the root node I get the following:

```
<Element '{http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v29_0}ResponseMessage' at 0x3015730>
<Element '{http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v29_0}FlightDetailsList' at 0x30157b0>
<Element '{http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v29_0}AirSegmentList' at 0x3015630>
<Element '{http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v29_0}FareInfoList' at 0x3015d30>
<Element '{http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v29_0}RouteList' at 0x3015fb0>
<Element '{http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v29_0}AirPricingSolution' at 0x3033030>
<Element '{http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v29_0}AirPricingSolution' at 0x2fec7d0>
<Element '{http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v29_0}AirPricingSolution' at 0x3033b90>
```

My issue is I'd like to be able to get rid of the {http://.....} section when creating the element tree so when I turn it into a dictionary it's more work-able. What is the best way to do that? Also I'm not 100% sold on etrees, if anyone has a better solution please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *So far I'm using xml.etree.ElementTree but it's not working properly*. It is working as expected. There is nothing improper about "the {http://.....} section". See https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces.

Comment: You are correct, I've found out how to sort of get rid of them (or minimize them really) by using namespaces. Thank you.